# Matplotlib : Why doesn't legend font appear as Latex rendering

Tags: fonts, pdftex, legend, math-fonts, matplotlib

Below the PDF output generated by a Python script :

[image: example]

As you can see, labels and title are correctly appearing as Latex rendering.
Excepted the fact that Latex font is not applied for legend and I don't understand why.

Here the Python script :

```
rc_fonts = {
    "text.usetex": True,
}
plt.rcParams.update(rc_fonts)

fig, axes = plt.subplots()
plt.xscale('log')
plt.xlabel(r'$1/\sigma$', fontsize=10, fontweight='bold')
plt.ylabel(r'FoM - GCsp + XC', fontsize=10, fontweight='bold')
plt.title(r'FoM - GCsp + XC vs 1/$\sigma$ for $\alpha = b_{sp}/b_{ph}$', fontsize=10, fontweight='bold')
array_z_fid = [ '0.9595', '1.087', '1.2395', '1.45', '1.688' ]
x_major = mpl.ticker.LogLocator(base = 10.0, numticks = 20)
axes.yaxis.set_major_locator(x_major)
x_minor = mpl.ticker.LogLocator(base = 10.0, subs = np.arange(1.0, 10.0)*0.1, numticks = 10)
axes.xaxis.set_minor_locator(x_minor)
axes.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))

# Plot each curve
inv_sigma = 1./sigma
axes.plot(inv_sigma, FoM_final, label=r'common bias - bin : '+str(j+1)+' ; z = '+array_z_fid[j])
# Legend
axes.legend(fontsize=8, loc="best")
```

If someone could indicate me how to apply Latex font for legend, this would be fine.

ps : just a last remark, in my code snippet, why can't I put `$\alpha = b_{\text{sp}}/b_{\text{ph}}$` to get `sp` and `ph` vertical subscript ?

Comment: Your example isn't complete (you're missing a few `import`s), and the `sigma`, `FoM_final` and `j` variables aren't defined.

Comment: You can't use `\text{sp}` because the default LaTeX preamble used by `matplotlib` doesn't load `amsmath` (or anything else providing `\text`). You can fix this by changing the used preamble using the `rcParams` field `'pfg.preamble'` like so: `mpl.rcParams.update({'pgf.preamble': r'\usepackage{amsmath}'})` (add any package you need here).

Comment: Without any package, you could've used `\mathrm` instead of `\text` or something similar to get upright subscripts.

Comment: Also, adding the missing `import`s and variable definitions, I can't reproduce your issue, for me the legend is rendered through LaTeX.

Comment: If you don't use the `'pgf'` backend, you can also change the used preamble with `plt.rc('text.latex', preamble=r'\usepackage{amsmath}')` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41453758/6783373).